# @Value not set via Java-configured test context

Tags: java, spring, testing, properties, junit

I've got a Maven project which uses Java-configured Spring (`@Configuration` etc.). Properties which are referenced by `@Value` are stored in different places, e.g. Tomcat's context.xml.

For testing I've created a .properties file to provide some values for the components and services. In my JUnit test (which uses a spring test context) this .properties file is added via `@PropertySource`. The **problem** is that the values will not be loaded from the file, instead the value identifier is set as value, e.g. `${someFlag:false}` (so I get ClassCastExceptions for any other than String). Also the default value will not be set, so I think, the values won't be processed at all.

I'm sure Spring finds this file because when I change the value of `@PropertySource` I get some FileNotFoundException. Nevertheless I've tried different variants to point to this file an all have worked (tested by renaming which produced FileNotFoundException):

- classpath:/test.properties (my preferred notation)
- /test.properties
- file:src/test/resources/test.properties

I'm also sure that Spring itself works, because when I remove the `@Value`, the class under test is injected via `@Autowired` in my test as expected.

Down below you'll find the problem scenario stripped down as much as possible. For versions and dependencies please see the pom.xml at the bottom.

### MyService.java

```
package my.package.service;

// Imports

@Service
public class MyService {

    @Value("${someFlag:false}")
    private Boolean someFlag;

    public boolean hasFlag() {
        return BooleanUtils.isTrue(someFlag);
    }
}
```

### MyConfiguration.java

```
@Configuration
@ComponentScan(basePackages = {"my.package.service"})
public class MyConfiguration {
}
```

### MyServiceComponentTest.java

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@ContextConfiguration(classes = {MyTestConfiguration.class})
public class MyServiceComponentTest {

    @Autowired
    private MyService service;

    @Test
    public void hasFlagReturnsTrue() {
        assertThat(service.hasFlag(), is(true));
    }
}
```

### MyTestConfiguration.java

```
@Configuration
@Import({MyConfiguration.class})
@PropertySource("classpath:/test.properties")
public class MyTestConfiguration {
}
```

### src/test/resources/test.properties

```
someFlag=true
```

### pom.xml

```
<properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    <spring.version>3.2.3.RELEASE</spring.version>
</properties>
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-lang3</artifactId>
        <version>3.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>
        <version>${spring.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
        <version>${spring.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <!-- Test dependencies -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-test</artifactId>
        <version>${spring.version}</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hamcrest</groupId>
        <artifactId>hamcrest-library</artifactId>
        <version>1.3</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>junit</groupId>
        <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
        <version>4.11</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

Answer (score 29, accepted):

The issue here is you need a `PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer` also which is actually responsible for resolving the `${..}` fields, just add another bean which creates this bean:

```
@Bean
public static PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer propertiesResolver() {
    return new PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer();
}
```

Comment: See the [javadoc](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.2.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/context/annotation/PropertySource.html) for `PropertySource`, see `Resolving ${...} placeholders in <bean> and @Value annotations`

Comment: Also, see the answer [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14942304/springs-javaconfig-and-customscopeconfigurer-issue). A `PropertySourcesPlaceHolderConfigurer` is a `BeanFactoryPostProcessor`.

Comment: It may work in some situations if Spring generates some beans after your `propertiesResolver()` is called, but it will fail otherwise. To make sure it works, you need to make it `static`.

Comment: When using XML, this will work
This happens automatically when using <context:property-placeholder> in XML
https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/3.2.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/context/annotation/PropertySource.html

Answer (score 3):

With Spring 4, it's now possible to use [TestPropertySource](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/test/context/TestPropertySource.html):

```
@TestPropertySource(value="classpath:/config/test.properties")
```

In order to load specific properties for a junit test

Comment: can you expand your comment?

Comment: I have tested `@TestPropertySource` together with `@Value` and properties were not loaded...

Comment: you need also to follow Biju's answer.

Answer (score 2):

In addition to Biju Kunjummen answer:

If you use @ConfigurationProperties to inject properties into bean setters, then ConfigurationPropertiesBindingPostProcessor need to be created (instead of PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer):

```
@Configuration
static class PropertyConfig {
    @Bean
    public static ConfigurationPropertiesBindingPostProcessor propertiesProcessor() {
        return new ConfigurationPropertiesBindingPostProcessor();
    }
}
```