# @TestPropertySource doesn't work for JUnit test with AnnotationConfigContextLoader in Spring 1.2.6

Tags: java, spring, junit, spring-boot

It doesn't seem that anything I do in Spring 4.1.17 with Spring Boot 1.2.6.RELEASE works at all.  I just want to access the application properties and override them with test if necessary (without using the hack to inject a PropertySource manually)

this doesn't work..

```
@TestPropertySource(properties = {"elastic.index=test_index"})
```

nor does this..

```
@TestPropertySource(locations = "/classpath:document.properties")
```

nor this..

```
@PropertySource("classpath:/document.properties")
```

full test case..

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@ContextConfiguration(loader = AnnotationConfigContextLoader.class)
@TestPropertySource(properties = {"elastic.index=test_index"})
public class PropertyTests {
    @Value("${elastic.index}")
    String index;

    @Configuration
    @TestPropertySource(properties = {"elastic.index=test_index"})
    static class ContextConfiguration {
    }

    @Test
    public void wtf() {
        assertEquals("test_index", index);
    }
}
```

resulting in

```
org.junit.ComparisonFailure: 
Expected :test_index
Actual   :${elastic.index}
```

It seems there is a lot of conflicting information between 3.x and 4.x and I can't find anything that will work for sure.

Any insight would be gratefully appreciated.  Cheers!

Comment: `TestPropertySource` works.

Comment: TestPropertySource does not override environment variables as it should according to https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/boot-features-external-config.html

Comment: Spring boot provides the annotation @SpringBootTest which can be used to read the config yml. Please check here for details : https://stackoverflow.com/a/50309219/1169093

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Your use of @Value requires a PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer bean to resolve `${...}` placeholders. See the accepted answer here: [@Value not set via Java-configured test context](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17600605/value-not-set-via-java-configured-test-context)

Comment: Right, the question is why?  This seems like a huge oversight.  Why did this feature go away?  Anyway.. if this is the only way.. then so be it.. though @TestPropertySource should work..

Comment: @Don Bottstein: Could you please highlight the Sources part of PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer, as i suppose a lot of people like myself overlook the part, when they already have a PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer available, which is not enough.

Answer (score 18):

I used the `locations` property of `@TestPropertySource` to override (or add) properties.

This worked for me (spring 4.2.4):

```
@TestPropertySource(locations = {
   "classpath:test.properties",
   "classpath:test-override.properties" })
```

But overriding properties like below didn't:

```
@TestPropertySource(
  locations = {"classpath:test.properties"},
  properties = { "key=value" })
```

Even though the javadoc says that those properties have highest precedence. A bug maybe?

**Update**

The bug should be fixed in Spring boot version 1.4.0 and up. See the [commit which closes the issue](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/commit/a37ae5d55629b95dcfbf87e7aa3a60354d017670).
By now, properties declared in the presented way should get precedence.

Comment: Indeed seems like a bug: https://jira.spring.io/browse/SPR-14068 https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/issues/4828

Comment: This worked for me as well in Spring 2.5.7.  Please note however that it does not work for YAML files because they're evidently not supported (ref: comment by @Sym-Sym [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38711871/load-different-application-yml-in-springboot-test))

Answer (score 17):

Turns out the best way (until Spring fixes this oversight) is to a `PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer` that will bring in test.properties (or whatever you want) and `@Import` or extend that `@Configuration`.

```
import org.apache.commons.lang3.ArrayUtils;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.core.io.support.PathMatchingResourcePatternResolver;

import java.io.IOException;

@Configuration
public class PropertyTestConfiguration {
    @Bean
    public PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer propertyPlaceholderConfigurer() throws IOException {
        final PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer ppc = new PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer();
        ppc.setLocations(ArrayUtils.addAll(
                        new PathMatchingResourcePatternResolver().getResources("classpath*:application.properties"),
                        new PathMatchingResourcePatternResolver().getResources("classpath*:test.properties")
                )
        );

        return ppc;
    }

}
```

This allows you to define defaults in application.properties and override them in test.properties.  Of course, if you have multiple schemes, then you can configure the `PropertyTestConfiguration` class as necessary.

And use this in a unit test.

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@ContextConfiguration(loader = AnnotationConfigContextLoader.class)
public class PropertyTests {
    @Value("${elastic.index}")
    String index;

    @Configuration
    @Import({PropertyTestConfiguration.class})
    static class ContextConfiguration {
    }
}
```

Comment: All you really need is a `PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer` in your application context, then the `@PropertySource` will work.

Comment: You can do this in your `@Configuration` class (formatting doesn't work here):  

    public @Bean PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer propertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer() {
        return new PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer();
    }

Answer (score 9):

If you have this problem and you're trying with yaml as properties file keep in mind that spring `@TestPropertySource` and `@PropertySource` doesn't work with yaml file, and properties won't be loaded properly.

https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/issues/10772#issuecomment-339581902

Answer (score 5):

For Me @TestPropertySource("classpath:xxxxxxxx.properties") worked

Answer (score 3):

Have you tried using `@PropertySource("classpath:document.properties")` or `@PropertySource("classpath*:document.properties")` ?

Comment: Tried both.  They introduced @TestPropertySource in 4.x, though it seems buggy.

Comment: Yeah. I remember I faced the same issue during the Integration Test. I hope they'll fix it soon if they haven't already.

Comment: @ThomasBeauvais do you have a reference to issue id? I would like to track if they have solved it

Answer (score 0):

I had issue with @TestPropertySource. test.properties not found

below is the one before fixed

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@ContextConfiguration(classes = ExtContext.class)
@TestPropertySource(locations = "classpath: test.properties")
```

i removed space between classpath: and test.properties as below

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@ContextConfiguration(classes = ExtContext.class)
@TestPropertySource(locations = "classpath:test.properties")
```

This worked for me, When test.properties is not found in classpth. misht work for you aswell