# Load different application.yml in SpringBoot Test

Tags: spring-mvc, spring-boot

I'm using a Spring Boot app which runs my `src/main/resources/config/application.yml` file.

When I run my test case by :

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@SpringApplicationConfiguration(classes = Application.class)
@WebAppConfiguration
@IntegrationTest
public class MyIntTest{
}
```

The test codes still run my application.yml file to load properties.
I wonder if it is possible to run another `*.yml` file when running the test case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have tested @IlyaSerbis answer and it is working for me. I am using Spring Boot 2.3.

I have tested these scenarios and it worked.

**Scenario1 -** First I have created `application.yml` for jUnit purpose and put it under `src/test/resources/config` (same path as the main application.yml) and it completely replacing the original yaml file ( not overwrite). That means it will not use any of the properties mentioned in `application.yml` of `src/main/resources/config` directory (main directory).

**Note:** In `Scenario1`, the path of application.yml in main and test need to be exactly same. If `src/main/resources/config/application.yml` then `src/test/resources/config/application.yml`. If `src/main/resources/application.yml` then `src/test/resources/application.yml`

**Scenario2 -** Then I created `application-test.yml` instead of `application.yml` under `src/test/resources/config` and using `@ActiveProfiles("test")`, I could see jUnit is taking property values from `application-test.yml`  (overwriting `application.yml` for common properties) and then taking values from `application.yml` as well which is not mentioned in `application-test.yml`.

Comment: using 2.3.12.RELEASE, application.yml under src/test/resources/config seems be merged by overring its values over that of  src/main/resources/application.yml

Answer (score 143):

One option is to work with profiles. Create a file called **application-test.yml**, move all properties you need for those tests to that file and then add the `@ActiveProfiles` annotation to your test class:

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@SpringApplicationConfiguration(classes = Application.class)
@WebAppConfiguration
@IntegrationTest
@ActiveProfiles("test") // Like this
public class MyIntTest{
}
```

Be aware, it will additionally load the application-test.yml, so all properties that are in application.yml are still going to be applied as well. If you don't want that, either use a profile for those as well, or override them in your application-test.yml.

Comment: This is the correct answer. The annotation TestPropertySource only works for .properties or .xml file.
See "Supported File formats sections" in https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/test/context/TestPropertySource.html

Comment: This works nicely but if you do this I would advise that you also have some tests that **don't** use the "test" profile. The fact that the test application yaml is merged with the actual application yml can cause the application to run fine in unit test but then have issues when run standalone.

Comment: I guess that's the best way to test if the configuration file is formatted correctly for a profile. This means that we would need N tests empty tests just loading the Spring context for each of the N profiles to test that, any other ideas?

Answer (score 40):

You can set your test properties in `src/test/resources/config/application.yml` file. Spring Boot test cases will take properties from `application.yml` file in **test** directory.

The `config` folder is predefined in Spring Boot.

As per documentation:

> If you do not like application.properties as the configuration file name, you can switch to another file name by specifying a spring.config.name environment property. You can also refer to an explicit location by using the spring.config.location environment property (which is a comma-separated list of directory locations or file paths). The following example shows how to specify a different file name:

```
java -jar myproject.jar --spring.config.location=classpath:/default.properties,classpath:/override.properties
```

The same works for `application.yml`

Documentation:

https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/spring-boot-features.html#boot-features-external-config-application-property-files

https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/boot-features-external-config.html#boot-features-external-config-application-property-files

Comment: Actually , at the very first ,the yml file for testing is at that path, i.e."src/test/resources/config/application.yml".But I don't know why it is not loaded when I ran my test case

Comment: I was using Intellij IDEA and did not have `<include>**/*.yml</include>` in the `<testResource>` of my `pom.xml`. As IDEA uses the `pom.xml` configuration as its primary model for compiling your code (even outside of `mvn` runs!), this meant that my `src/test/resources/application.yml` was not being picked up by my test, because it was not present in `target/test-classes`.

Comment: This should be marked as correct answer, because it is the case for YAML files. I have confirmed with Spring Boot Team that TestPropertySource does not support YAML files.[Spring Boot JIRA](https://jira.spring.io/browse/SPR-16563)

Comment: Does anybody know how to force springboot to replace @placeholder@ in yml while testing? Why they force me to statically input data?

Comment: Note that name of the subdirectory (`config`) isn't arbitrary but is predefined. For details see [Spring Boot documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/boot-features-external-config.html#boot-features-external-config-application-property-files) and the source code of the ConfigFileApplicationListener.load() method.

Comment: @SimonLogic Checkout Maven resources plugin

Comment: Hi @TheKojuEffect, are you sure that Spring Boot test cases will take properties from test directory? The [Externalized Configuration](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/spring-boot-features.html#boot-features-external-config) did not say that.

Comment: Terrible behavior. Separation of concerns maybe??? configs from the src dir have NOTHING to do with running tests. If anything, a useful message should be logged, stating that no default config could be found in the default location they describe.

Answer (score 22):

You can use **`@TestPropertySource`** to load different properties/yaml file

```
@TestPropertySource(locations="classpath:test.properties")
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@SpringApplicationConfiguration(Application.class)
public class MyIntTest{

}
```

OR if you want to **override** only specific properties/yaml you can use

```
@TestPropertySource(
        properties = {
                "spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=validate",
                "liquibase.enabled=false"
        }
)
```

Comment: I tried using this annotation but in the test it still looks for the `application.yml` instead of the one I specify.

Comment: Like explained already, this works only for .properties file, as the annotation does not have support for yaml files. This really is not an answer to the question.

Answer (score 18):

If you need to have production `application.yml` completely replaced then put its test version to the same path but in test environment (usually it is `src/test/resources/`)

But if you need to override or add some properties then you have few options.

Option 1: put test `application.yml` in `src/test/resources/config/` directory as @TheKojuEffect suggests in his [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38720161/355438).

Option 2: use [profile-specific properties](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/boot-features-external-config.html#boot-features-external-config-profile-specific-properties): create say `application-test.yml` in your `src/test/resources/` folder and:

- add `@ActiveProfiles` annotation to your test classes:

  ```
  @SpringBootTest(classes = Application.class)
  @ActiveProfiles("test")
  public class MyIntTest {
  ```
- or alternatively set `spring.profiles.active` property value in `@SpringBootTest` annotation:

  ```
  @SpringBootTest(
          properties = ["spring.profiles.active=test"],
          classes = Application.class,
  )
  public class MyIntTest {
  ```

This works not only with `@SpringBootTest` but with `@JsonTest`, `@JdbcTests`, `@DataJpaTest` and other slice test annotations as well.

And you can set as many profiles as you want (`spring.profiles.active=dev,hsqldb`) - see farther details in documentation on [Profiles](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/boot-features-profiles.html).

Comment: This is correct. I have tested these scenarios and it worked. First I have created `application.yml` for jUnit purpose and put it under `src/test/resources/` (same path as the main application.yml) and it completely replacing the original yaml file ( not overwrite). Then I created `application-test.yml` instead of `application.yml` under `src/test/resources/` and using `@ActiveProfiles("test")`, I could see jUnit is taking property values from `application-test.yml`  (overwriting `application.yml` for common properties) and then taking values from `application.yml` as well.

Answer (score 14):

**Spring-boot** framework allows us to provide **YAML** files as a replacement for the **.properties file** and it is convenient.The keys in property files can be provided in YAML format in **application.yml** file in the resource folder and spring-boot will automatically take it up.Keep in mind that the yaml format has to keep the spaces correct for the value to be read correctly.

You can use the `@Value("${property}")` to inject the values from the YAML files.
Also **Spring.active.profiles** can be given to differentiate between different YAML for different environments for convenient deployment.

***For testing purposes***, the test YAML file can be named like *application-test.yml* and placed in the resource folder of the test directory.

If you are specifying the `application-test.yml` and provide the spring test profile in the .yml, then you can use the `@ActiveProfiles('test')` annotation to direct spring to take the configurations from the ***application-test.yml*** that you have specified.

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@SpringBootTest(classes = ApplicationTest.class)
@ActiveProfiles("test")
public class MyTest {
 ...
}
```

If you are using JUnit 5 then no need for other annotations as ***@SpringBootTest*** already include the springrunner annotation. Keeping a separate main ApplicationTest.class enables us to provide separate configuration classes for tests and we can prevent the default configuration beans from loading by excluding them from a component scan in the test main class. You can also provide the profile to be loaded there.

```
@SpringBootApplication(exclude=SecurityAutoConfiguration.class)
public class ApplicationTest {
 
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(ApplicationTest.class, args);
    }
}
```

Here is the link for Spring documentation regarding the use of YAML instead of `.properties`  file(s): https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/boot-features-external-config.html

Answer (score 5):

See this: [Spring @PropertySource using YAML](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21271468/spring-propertysource-using-yaml)

I think the 3rd answer has what you're looking for, i.e have a separate POJO to map your yaml values into:

```
@ConfigurationProperties(path="classpath:/appprops.yml", name="db")
public class DbProperties {
    private String url;
    private String username;
    private String password;
...
}
```

Then annotate your test class with this:

```
@EnableConfigurationProperties(DbProperties.class)
public class PropertiesUsingService {

    @Autowired private DbProperties dbProperties;

}
```

Answer (score 5):

A simple working configuration using

@TestPropertySource and **properties**

```java
@SpringBootTest
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@TestPropertySource(properties = {"spring.config.location=classpath:another.yml"})
public class TestClass {


    @Test

    public void someTest() {
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Starting with Spring 4.1, We can directly set the property in application.yml using the [@TestPropertySource](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/test/context/TestPropertySource.html) annotation.

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@SpringBootTest
@TestPropertySource(properties = {"yoursection.yourparameter=your_value"})
public MyIntTest
{
 //your test methods
}
```

Just convert your yaml parameters into complete property structure. 
For example:
If content of application.yml is like below

```
yoursection:
  yourparameter:your_value
```

Then value to go inside the @TestPropertySource will be,

```
yoursection.yourparameter=your_value
```

Answer (score 2):

This might be considered one of the options. now if you wanted to load a yml file ( which did not get loaded by default on applying the above annotations) the trick is to use

```
@ContextConfiguration(classes= {...}, initializers={ConfigFileApplicationContextInitializer.class})
```

Here is a sample code

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@ActiveProfiles("test")
@DirtiesContext
@ContextConfiguration(classes= {DataSourceTestConfig.class}, initializers = {ConfigFileApplicationContextInitializer.class})
public class CustomDateDeserializerTest {


    private ObjectMapper objMapper;

    @Before
    public void setUp() {
        objMapper = new ObjectMapper();

    }

    @Test
    public void test_dateDeserialization() {

    }
}
```

Again make sure that the setup config java file  -  here `DataSourceTestConfig.java` contains the following property values.

```
@Configuration
@ActiveProfiles("test")
@TestPropertySource(properties = { "spring.config.location=classpath:application-test.yml" })
public class DataSourceTestConfig implements EnvironmentAware {

    private Environment env;

    @Bean
    @Profile("test")
    public DataSource testDs() {
       HikariDataSource ds = new HikariDataSource();

        boolean isAutoCommitEnabled = env.getProperty("spring.datasource.hikari.auto-commit") != null ? Boolean.parseBoolean(env.getProperty("spring.datasource.hikari.auto-commit")):false;
        ds.setAutoCommit(isAutoCommitEnabled);
        // Connection test query is for legacy connections
        //ds.setConnectionInitSql(env.getProperty("spring.datasource.hikari.connection-test-query"));
        ds.setPoolName(env.getProperty("spring.datasource.hikari.pool-name"));
        ds.setDriverClassName(env.getProperty("spring.datasource.driver-class-name"));
        long timeout = env.getProperty("spring.datasource.hikari.idleTimeout") != null ? Long.parseLong(env.getProperty("spring.datasource.hikari.idleTimeout")): 40000;
        ds.setIdleTimeout(timeout);
        long maxLifeTime = env.getProperty("spring.datasource.hikari.maxLifetime") != null ? Long.parseLong(env.getProperty("spring.datasource.hikari.maxLifetime")): 1800000 ;
        ds.setMaxLifetime(maxLifeTime);
        ds.setJdbcUrl(env.getProperty("spring.datasource.url"));
        ds.setPoolName(env.getProperty("spring.datasource.hikari.pool-name"));
        ds.setUsername(env.getProperty("spring.datasource.username"));
        ds.setPassword(env.getProperty("spring.datasource.password"));
        int poolSize = env.getProperty("spring.datasource.hikari.maximum-pool-size") != null ? Integer.parseInt(env.getProperty("spring.datasource.hikari.maximum-pool-size")): 10;
        ds.setMaximumPoolSize(poolSize);

        return ds;
    }

    @Bean
    @Profile("test")
    public JdbcTemplate testJdbctemplate() {
        return new JdbcTemplate(testDs());
    }

    @Bean
    @Profile("test")
    public NamedParameterJdbcTemplate testNamedTemplate() {
        return new NamedParameterJdbcTemplate(testDs());
    }

    @Override
    public void setEnvironment(Environment environment) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        this.env = environment;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Lu55 Option 1 how to...

Add test only application.yml inside a seperated resources folder.

```
├── main
│   ├── java
│   └── resources
│       ├── application.yml
└── test
    ├── java
    └── resources
        └── application.yml
```

In this project structure the application.yml under main is loaded if the code under main is running, the application.yml under test is used in a test.

To setup this structure add a new Package folder test/recources if not present.

Eclipse right click on your project -> Properties -> Java Build Path -> Source Tab  -> (Dialog ont the rigth side) "Add Folder ..."

Inside Source Folder Selection -> mark test -> click on "Create New Folder ..." button -> type "resources" inside the Textfeld -> Click the "Finish" button.

After pushing the "Finisch" button  you can see the sourcefolder {projectname}/src/test/recources (new)

Optional: Arrange folder sequence for the Project Explorer view.
Klick on Order and Export Tab mark and move {projectname}/src/test/recources to bottom.
Apply and Close
!!! Clean up Project !!!

Eclipse -> Project -> Clean ...

Now there is a separated yaml for test and the main application.

Answer (score 0):

We can use @SpringBootTest annotation which loads the yml file from src\main\java\com...hence when we execute the unit test, all of the properties are already there in the config properties class.

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@SpringBootTest
public class AddressFieldsTest {

    @InjectMocks
    AddressFieldsValidator addressFieldsValidator;

    @Autowired
    AddressFieldsConfig addressFieldsConfig;
    ...........

    @Before
    public void setUp() throws Exception{
        MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(this);
        ReflectionTestUtils.setField(addressFieldsValidator,"addressFieldsConfig", addressFieldsConfig);
    }

}
```

We can use @Value annotation if you have few configs or other wise we can use a config properties class. For e.g

```
@Data
@Component
@RefreshScope
@ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "address.fields.regex")
public class AddressFieldsConfig {

    private int firstName;
    private int lastName;
    .........
```

Answer (score 0):

There are several solutions. The easiest and self-describing is based on `spring.config.location` property. `@TestPropertySource` has highest precedence, so the property goes there.

Following example demonstrates minimal Spring Boot test:

```java
@ExtendWith(SpringExtension.class)
@ContextConfiguration(initializers = {ConfigDataApplicationContextInitializer.class})
@TestPropertySource(properties = {"spring.config.location=classpath:debug.yml"})
@EnableConfigurationProperties({DataSourceProperties.class})
public class MyTest {
    @Autowired DataSourceProperties dbProps;

    @Test
    public void test() {
        System.out.println(dbProps.getUrl());
    }
}
```

`ConfigDataApplicationContextInitializer` is hidden when you use `@SpringBootTest`. `@EnableConfigurationProperties` is here because we slicing execution environment to minimum (no auto-scanning!).

`spring.config.location` property overrides default search strategy, like `classpath:application.yml` - nice if you want a completely separated config!

`spring.config.location` allows to specify a list of locations with comma:

```
classpath:common.yml,file:./config/local.yml
```

Some control is possible with `spring.config.name`.

Another way is to use `@PropertySource(factory = ...)` for YAML files (because Spring Framework only supports XML & `.properties` config files):

```
@PropertySource(value = {"file:./local.yml"}, factory = MyTest.YamlPropertySourceFactory.class)
public class MyTest {

    public static class YamlPropertySourceFactory implements PropertySourceFactory {
        @Override
        public org.springframework.core.env.PropertySource<?> createPropertySource(String name, EncodedResource resource) throws IOException {
            YamlPropertiesFactoryBean factory = new YamlPropertiesFactoryBean();
            factory.setResources(resource.getResource());
            return new PropertiesPropertySource(resource.getResource().getFilename(), factory.getObject());
        }
    }
    ...
}
```