# Load different application.yml in test Spring Boot

Tags: spring, spring-boot, unit-testing, yaml

I have a problem and I can't load a YML in the main tests. I currently have an **application.yml** in the `src > main > resources > config > application.yml` path and I want it to take the `src > test > resources > config > application-test.yml`

I already tried using `@ActiveProfiles("test")`, but take the main route. I also tried `@Profile("test")` but it does nothing different.

I also tried simply to create the **application.yml** in the path `src > test > resources > config > application.yml`

Also put the annotation:

```
@SpringBootTest(
        properties = ["spring.profiles.active=test"],
        classes = Application.class,
)
```

Anyone knows how to solve this?

Comment: Have you checked this https://stackoverflow.com/a/53134737/5790498?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Load different application.yml in SpringBoot Test](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38711871/load-different-application-yml-in-springboot-test)

Comment: @Abhijeet Yes, is the same question but I tried everything they say and nothing worked.

Comment: @jdflores, you need to do one of these
1. move the file up from src/test/resources/config to src/test/resources
2. add @PropertySource() to specify the path to the properties
The default location for properties in a maven project structure is src/[main/test]/resources.
HTH

Comment: @sandboxbohemian I already tried to change the application.yml and it still doesn't work. I also tried the PropertySource() but read that it doesn't work for .YML files

Comment: Can you please have look at this. https://memorynotfound.com/spring-boot-managing-profiles-profile-annotation-example/