# Embedded MongoDb not picked up for Application test

Tags: java, spring, mongodb, spring-boot, spring-mvc

Application test `AuthServiceApplicationTests.class` is trying to run against **local** MongoDb instance which was setup for **development** and running behind the process. I shutdown this instance, and expected that it will run against embedded mongoDb with `de.flapdoodle.embed.mongo`.

```
<!-- Integration Tests -->
<dependency>
  <groupId>de.flapdoodle.embed</groupId>
  <artifactId>de.flapdoodle.embed.mongo</artifactId>
  <version>2.2.0</version>
  <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>
<!--/ Integration Tests -->
```

Played around with all possible combination of annotations. But nothing worked to run against the embedded mongoDB instance with success. Please see the error below:

> **Note:** The test run successfully, after restarting my dev mongoDb instance. But I have few questions in comments section, if you can
>   please put some light into those issues as well.

### Questions:

- For test environment, I tried to set the port `0` in `.properties`. So embedded mongoDb can pick up the **random port**. But it always complain for invalid port and it should be between **0 and 65535**. How can I set the random port for embedded mongoDB so it shouldn't run against dev or production mongoDB instance by **default**? Until explicitly required.
- When `de.flapdoodle.embed.mongo` doesn't work under the hood, so I tried another maven plugin according to this article [here](https://vladmihalcea.com/integration-testing-done-right-with-embedded-mongodb/). So `mvn clean -Dtest=AuthServiceApplicationTests test` should run the `embedmongo-maven-plugin` before running the actual test and setup the embedded mongoDb instance. But unfortunately, it didn't work out. Can you please let me know - why this plugin didn't even triggered in the maven plugin process chain?
- What is the purpose of `@DataMongoTest` and `@DataJpaTest`? And what's the difference between them?

### MongoDb Error Logs:

```
2020-04-21 14:45:36.062  INFO 94452 --- [           main] org.mongodb.driver.cluster               : Cluster created with settings {hosts=[localhost:27017], mode=SINGLE, requiredClusterType=UNKNOWN, serverSelectionTimeout='30000 ms', maxWaitQueueSize=500}
2020-04-21 14:45:36.781  INFO 94452 --- [localhost:27017] org.mongodb.driver.cluster               : **Exception in monitor thread while connecting to server localhost:27017**

com.mongodb.MongoSocketOpenException: Exception opening socket
        at com.mongodb.internal.connection.SocketStream.open(SocketStream.java:70) ~[mongodb-driver-core-3.11.2.jar:na]
        at com.mongodb.internal.connection.InternalStreamConnection.open(InternalStreamConnection.java:128) ~[mongodb-driver-core-3.11.2.jar:na]
        at com.mongodb.internal.connection.DefaultServerMonitor$ServerMonitorRunnable.run(DefaultServerMonitor.java:117) ~[mongodb-driver-core-3.11.2.jar:na]
        at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:830) ~[na:na]
Caused by: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused
        at java.base/sun.nio.ch.Net.pollConnect(Native Method) ~[na:na]
        at java.base/sun.nio.ch.Net.pollConnectNow(Net.java:579) ~[na:na]
        at java.base/sun.nio.ch.NioSocketImpl.timedFinishConnect(NioSocketImpl.java:542) ~[na:na]
        at java.base/sun.nio.ch.NioSocketImpl.connect(NioSocketImpl.java:597) ~[na:na]
        at java.base/java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(SocksSocketImpl.java:339) ~[na:na]
        at java.base/java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:603) ~[na:na]
        at com.mongodb.internal.connection.SocketStreamHelper.initialize(SocketStreamHelper.java:64) ~[mongodb-driver-core-3.11.2.jar:na]
        at com.mongodb.internal.connection.SocketStream.initializeSocket(SocketStream.java:79) ~[mongodb-driver-core-3.11.2.jar:na]
        at com.mongodb.internal.connection.SocketStream.open(SocketStream.java:65) ~[mongodb-driver-core-3.11.2.jar:na]
        ... 3 common frames omitted

2020-04-21 14:45:37.614  WARN 94452 --- [           main] o.s.data.convert.CustomConversions       : Registering converter from class java.time.LocalDateTime to class java.time.Instant as reading converter although it doesn't convert from a store-supported type! You might wanna check you annotation setup at the converter implementation.
2020-04-21 14:45:37.616  WARN 94452 --- [           main] o.s.data.convert.CustomConversions       : Registering converter from class java.time.Instant to class java.time.LocalDateTime as reading converter although it doesn't convert from a store-supported type! You might wanna check you annotation setup at the converter implementation.
2020-04-21 14:45:37.645  WARN 94452 --- [           main] o.s.data.convert.CustomConversions       : Registering converter from class java.time.LocalDateTime to class java.time.Instant as reading converter although it doesn't convert from a store-supported type! You might wanna check you annotation setup at the converter implementation.
2020-04-21 14:45:37.652  WARN 94452 --- [           main] o.s.data.convert.CustomConversions       : Registering converter from class java.time.Instant to class java.time.LocalDateTime as reading converter although it doesn't convert from a store-supported type! You might wanna check you annotation setup at the converter implementation.
2020-04-21 14:45:45.402  INFO 94452 --- [           main] o.s.b.a.h2.H2ConsoleAutoConfiguration    : H2 console available at '/h2-test'. Database available at 'jdbc:h2:mem:testdb'
2020-04-21 14:45:58.007  INFO 94452 --- [           main] org.mongodb.driver.cluster               : Cluster description not yet available. Waiting for 30000 ms before timing out
2020-04-21 14:46:28.020  WARN 94452 --- [           main] ConfigServletWebServerApplicationContext : Exception encountered during context initialization - cancelling refresh attempt: org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.WebSecurityConfiguration': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through method 'setFilterChainProxySecurityConfigurer' parameter 1; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanExpressionException: Expression parsing failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.security.oauth2.config.annotation.web.configuration.AuthorizationServerSecurityConfiguration': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.dao.DataAccessResourceFailureException: Timed out after 30000 ms while waiting to connect. Client view of cluster state is {type=UNKNOWN, servers=[{address=localhost:27017, type=UNKNOWN, state=CONNECTING, exception={com.mongodb.MongoSocketOpenException: Exception opening socket}, caused by {java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused}}]; nested exception is com.mongodb.MongoTimeoutException: Timed out after 30000 ms while waiting to connect. Client view of cluster state is {type=UNKNOWN, servers=[{address=localhost:27017, type=UNKNOWN, state=CONNECTING, exception={com.mongodb.MongoSocketOpenException: Exception opening socket}, caused by {java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused}}]
2020-04-21 14:46:28.098  INFO 94452 --- [           main] ConditionEvaluationReportLoggingListener : 

Error starting ApplicationContext. To display the conditions report re-run your application with 'debug' enabled.
2020-04-21 14:46:28.124 ERROR 94452 --- [           main] o.s.boot.SpringApplication               : Application run failed

org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.WebSecurityConfiguration': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through method 'setFilterChainProxySecurityConfigurer' parameter 1; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanExpressionException: Expression parsing failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.security.oauth2.config.annotation.web.configuration.AuthorizationServerSecurityConfiguration': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.dao.DataAccessResourceFailureException: Timed out after 30000 ms while waiting to connect. Client view of cluster state is {type=UNKNOWN, servers=[{address=localhost:27017, type=UNKNOWN, state=CONNECTING, exception={com.mongodb.MongoSocketOpenException: Exception opening socket}, caused by {java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused}}]; nested exception is com.mongodb.MongoTimeoutException: Timed out after 30000 ms while waiting to connect. Client view of cluster state is {type=UNKNOWN, servers=[{address=localhost:27017, type=UNKNOWN, state=CONNECTING, exception={com.mongodb.MongoSocketOpenException: Exception opening socket}, caused by {java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused}}]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredMethodElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:719) ~[spring-beans-5.2.0.RELEASE.jar:5.2.0.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InjectionMetadata.inject(InjectionMetadata.java:116) ~[spring-beans-5.2.0.RELEASE.jar:5.2.0.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessProperties(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:397) ~[spring-beans-5.2.0.RELEASE.jar:5.2.0.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1429) ~[spring-beans-5.2.0.RELEASE.jar:5.2.0.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:594) ~[spring-beans-5.2.0.RELEASE.jar:5.2.0.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:517) ~[spring-beans-5.2.0.RELEASE.jar:5.2.0.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:323) ~[spring-beans-5.2.0.RELEASE.jar:5.2.0.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:222) ~[spring-beans-5.2.0.RELEASE.jar:5.2.0.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:321) ~[spring-beans-5.2.0.RELEASE.jar:5.2.0.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:202) ~[spring-beans-5.2.0.RELEASE.jar:5.2.0.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:879) ~[spring-beans-5.2.0.RELEASE.jar:5.2.0.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:878) ~[spring-context-5.2.0.RELEASE.jar:5.2.0.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:550) ~[spring-context-5.2.0.RELEASE.jar:5.2.0.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.refresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:141) ~[spring-boot-2.2.6.RELEASE.jar:2.2.6.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:747) ~[spring-boot-2.2.6.RELEASE.jar:2.2.6.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:397) ~[spring-boot-2.2.6.RELEASE.jar:2.2.6.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:315) ~[spring-boot-2.2.6.RELEASE.jar:2.2.6.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.boot.test.context.SpringBootContextLoader.loadContext(SpringBootContextLoader.java:126) ~[spring-boot-test-2.2.6.RELEASE.jar:2.2.6.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.test.context.cache.DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.loadContextInternal(DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.java:99) ~[spring-test-5.2.0.RELEASE.jar:5.2.0.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.test.context.cache.DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.loadContext(DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.java:124) ~[spring-test-5.2.0.RELEASE.jar:5.2.0.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.test.context.support.DefaultTestContext.getApplicationContext(DefaultTestContext.java:123) ~[spring-test-5.2.0.RELEASE.jar:5.2.0.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.test.context.support.DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener.injectDependencies(DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener.java:118) ~[spring-test-5.2.0.RELEASE.jar:5.2.0.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.test.context.support.DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener.prepareTestInstance(DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener.java:83) ~[spring-test-5.2.0.RELEASE.jar:5.2.0.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.boot.test.autoconfigure.SpringBootDependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener.prepareTestInstance(SpringBootDependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener.java:43) ~[spring-boot-test-autoconfigure-2.2.6.RELEASE.jar:2.2.6.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.test.context.TestContextManager.prepareTestInstance(TestContextManager.java:244) ~[spring-test-5.2.0.RELEASE.jar:5.2.0.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.test.context.junit.jupiter.SpringExtension.postProcessTestInstance(SpringExtension.java:98) ~[spring-test-5.2.0.RELEASE.jar:5.2.0.RELEASE]
        at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.ClassBasedTestDescriptor.lambda$invokeTestInstancePostProcessors$5(ClassBasedTestDescriptor.java:337) ~[junit-jupiter-engine-5.5.2.jar:5.5.2]
        at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.ClassBasedTestDescriptor.executeAndMaskThrowable(ClassBasedTestDescriptor.java:342) ~[junit-jupiter-engine-5.5.2.jar:5.5.2]
        at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.ClassBasedTestDescriptor.lambda$invokeTestInstancePostProcessors$6(ClassBasedTestDescriptor.java:337) ~[junit-jupiter-engine-5.5.2.jar:5.5.2]
        at java.base/java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline$3$1.accept(ReferencePipeline.java:195) ~[na:na]
        at java.base/java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline$2$1.accept(ReferencePipeline.java:177) ~[na:na]
        at java.base/java.util.ArrayList$ArrayListSpliterator.forEachRemaining(ArrayList.java:1621) ~[na:na]
        at java.base/java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.copyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:484) ~[na:na]
        at java.base/java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.wrapAndCopyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:474) ~[na:na]
        at java.base/java.util.stream.StreamSpliterators$WrappingSpliterator.forEachRemaining(StreamSpliterators.java:312) ~[na:na]
        at java.base/java.util.stream.Streams$ConcatSpliterator.forEachRemaining(Streams.java:735) ~[na:na]
        at java.base/java.util.stream.Streams$ConcatSpliterator.forEachRemaining(Streams.java:734) ~[na:na]
        at java.base/java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline$Head.forEach(ReferencePipeline.java:658) ~[na:na]
        at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.ClassBasedTestDescriptor.invokeTestInstancePostProcessors(ClassBasedTestDescriptor.java:336) ~[junit-jupiter-engine-5.5.2.jar:5.5.2]
        at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.ClassBasedTestDescriptor.instantiateAndPostProcessTestInstance(ClassBasedTestDescriptor.java:259) ~[junit-jupiter-engine-5.5.2.jar:5.5.2]
        at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.ClassBasedTestDescriptor.lambda$testInstancesProvider$2(ClassBasedTestDescriptor.java:252) ~[junit-jupiter-engine-5.5.2.jar:5.5.2]
        at java.base/java.util.Optional.orElseGet(Optional.java:362) ~[na:na]
        at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.ClassBasedTestDescriptor.lambda$testInstancesProvider$3(ClassBasedTestDescriptor.java:251) ~[junit-jupiter-engine-5.5.2.jar:5.5.2]
        at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.TestInstancesProvider.getTestInstances(TestInstancesProvider.java:29) ~[junit-jupiter-engine-5.5.2.jar:5.5.2]
        at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.TestMethodTestDescriptor.lambda$prepare$0(TestMethodTestDescriptor.java:106) ~[junit-jupiter-engine-5.5.2.jar:5.5.2]
        at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73) ~[junit-platform-engine-1.5.2.jar:1.5.2]
        at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.TestMethodTestDescriptor.prepare(TestMethodTestDescriptor.java:105) ~[junit-jupiter-engine-5.5.2.jar:5.5.2]
        at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.TestMethodTestDescriptor.prepare(TestMethodTestDescriptor.java:69) ~[junit-jupiter-engine-5.5.2.jar:5.5.2]
        at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$prepare$1(NodeTestTask.java:107) ~[junit-platform-engine-1.5.2.jar:1.5.2]
        at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73) ~[junit-platform-engine-1.5.2.jar:1.5.2]
        at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.prepare(NodeTestTask.java:107) ~[junit-platform-engine-1.5.2.jar:1.5.2]
        at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.execute(NodeTestTask.java:75) ~[junit-platform-engine-1.5.2.jar:1.5.2]
        at java.base/java.util.ArrayList.forEach(ArrayList.java:1507) ~[na:na]
        at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.invokeAll(SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.java:38) ~[junit-platform-engine-1.5.2.jar:1.5.2]
        at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$5(NodeTestTask.java:139) ~[junit-platform-engine-1.5.2.jar:1.5.2]
        at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73) ~[junit-platform-engine-1.5.2.jar:1.5.2]
        at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$7(NodeTestTask.java:125) ~[junit-platform-engine-1.5.2.jar:1.5.2]
        at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.Node.around(Node.java:135) ~[junit-platform-engine-1.5.2.jar:1.5.2]
        at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$8(NodeTestTask.java:123) ~[junit-platform-engine-1.5.2.jar:1.5.2]
        at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73) ~[junit-platform-engine-1.5.2.jar:1.5.2]
        at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.executeRecursively(NodeTestTask.java:122) ~[junit-platform-engine-1.5.2.jar:1.5.2]
        at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.execute(NodeTestTask.java:80) ~[junit-platform-engine-1.5.2.jar:1.5.2]
        at java.base/java.util.ArrayList.forEach(ArrayList.java:1507) ~[na:na]
        at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.invokeAll(SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.java:38) ~[junit-platform-engine-1.5.2.jar:1.5.2]
        at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$5(NodeTestTask.java:139) ~[junit-platform-engine-1.5.2.jar:1.5.2]
        at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73) ~[junit-platform-engine-1.5.2.jar:1.5.2]
        at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$7(NodeTestTask.java:125) ~[junit-platform-engine-1.5.2.jar:1.5.2]
        at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.Node.around(Node.java:135) ~[junit-platform-engine-1.5.2.jar:1.5.2]
        at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$8(NodeTestTask.java:123) ~[junit-platform-engine-1.5.2.jar:1.5.2]
        at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73) ~[junit-platform-engine-1.5.2.jar:1.5.2]
        at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.executeRecursively(NodeTestTask.java:122) ~[junit-platform-engine-1.5.2.jar:1.5.2]
        at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.execute(NodeTestTask.java:80) ~[junit-platform-engine-1.5.2.jar:1.5.2]
        at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.submit(SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.java:32) ~[junit-platform-engine-1.5.2.jar:1.5.2]
        at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.HierarchicalTestExecutor.execute(HierarchicalTestExecutor.java:57) ~[junit-platform-engine-1.5.2.jar:1.5.2]
        at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.HierarchicalTestEngine.execute(HierarchicalTestEngine.java:51) ~[junit-platform-engine-1.5.2.jar:1.5.2]
        at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.DefaultLauncher.execute(DefaultLauncher.java:220) ~[junit-platform-launcher-1.3.1.jar:1.3.1]
        at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.DefaultLauncher.lambda$execute$6(DefaultLauncher.java:188) ~[junit-platform-launcher-1.3.1.jar:1.3.1]
        at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.DefaultLauncher.withInterceptedStreams(DefaultLauncher.java:202) ~[junit-platform-launcher-1.3.1.jar:1.3.1]
        at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.DefaultLauncher.execute(DefaultLauncher.java:181) ~[junit-platform-launcher-1.3.1.jar:1.3.1]
        at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.DefaultLauncher.execute(DefaultLauncher.java:128) ~[junit-platform-launcher-1.3.1.jar:1.3.1]
        at org.apache.maven.surefire.junitplatform.JUnitPlatformProvider.invokeAllTests(JUnitPlatformProvider.java:150) ~[surefire-junit-platform-2.22.2.jar:2.22.2]
        at org.apache.maven.surefire.junitplatform.JUnitPlatformProvider.invoke(JUnitPlatformProvider.java:124) ~[surefire-junit-platform-2.22.2.jar:2.22.2]
        at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ForkedBooter.invokeProviderInSameClassLoader(ForkedBooter.java:384) ~[surefire-booter-2.22.2.jar:2.22.2]
        at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ForkedBooter.runSuitesInProcess(ForkedBooter.java:345) ~[surefire-booter-2.22.2.jar:2.22.2]
        at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ForkedBooter.execute(ForkedBooter.java:126) ~[surefire-booter-2.22.2.jar:2.22.2]
        at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ForkedBooter.main(ForkedBooter.java:418) ~[surefire-booter-2.22.2.jar:2.22.2]
```

## Test Configurations

Please see my configuration setup and `AuthServiceApplicationTests` for main Application `AuthServiceApplication`.

**AppTestConfig**

```
@Configuration
@ComponentScan(basePackages = "com.authservice.application")
@TestPropertySource(locations = "classpath:application-test.yml")
@EnableConfigurationProperties
@EnableAutoConfiguration
public class AppTestConfig {

   ...
}
```

**TestMongoConfig**

```
@Configuration
@DataMongoTest
@DirtiesContext
public class TestMongoConfig {

    @Autowired
    private MongoProperties properties;

    @Autowired(required = false)
    private MongoClientOptions options;

    @Value("${spring.data.mongodb.database}")
    private String databaseName;

    @Value("${spring.data.mongodb.host}")
    private String hostName;

    @Value("${spring.data.mongodb.port}")
    private int port;

    @Bean(destroyMethod = "close")
    public MongoClient mongo(MongodProcess mongodProcess) throws IOException {
        Net net = mongodProcess.getConfig().net();
        properties.setHost(net.getServerAddress().getHostName());
        properties.setPort(net.getPort());
        return mongoClient(properties.getHost(), properties.getPort());
    }

//    @Bean
//    public MongoTemplate mongoTemplate() throws Exception {
//        return new MongoTemplate(mongoClient(), databaseName);
//    }

    public MongoClient mongoClient(String hostName, int port) {
        return MongoClients.create("mongodb://" + hostName + ":" + port);
    }

    @Bean(destroyMethod = "stop")
    public MongodProcess mongodProcess(MongodExecutable mongodExecutable) throws IOException {
        return mongodExecutable.start();
    }

    @Bean(destroyMethod = "stop")
    public MongodExecutable mongodExecutable(MongodStarter mongodStarter,
                                             @Qualifier("mongodConfig") IMongodConfig iMongodConfig) throws IOException {
        return mongodStarter.prepare(iMongodConfig);
    }

    @Bean
    public IMongodConfig mongodConfig() throws IOException {
        return new MongodConfigBuilder().version(Version.Main.PRODUCTION).build();
    }

    @Bean
    public MongodStarter mongodStarter() {
        return MongodStarter.getDefaultInstance();
    }
}
```

**Note:** I also have `MonoConfig` class in the main application which basically setup the mongoDB datasource from `application.properties`.

**AuthServiceApplicationTests**

```
@ExtendWith(SpringExtension.class)
@ContextConfiguration(classes = {
        AppTestConfig.class,
        TestMongoConfig.class,
        AuthServiceApplication.class
})
@SpringBootTest(classes = AuthServiceApplication.class,
        webEnvironment = SpringBootTest.WebEnvironment.RANDOM_PORT)
@ActiveProfiles("test")
class AuthServiceApplicationTests {

    @Test
    void contextLoads() {
        ...
    }
}
```

**application-test.properties**

```
spring:
  profiles:
      active: test

---
## MongoDB - Datasource Management
spring:
  data:
    mongodb:
      host: localhost
      database: testdb
      username: root
      password: root
      auto-index-creation: false
```

Comment: After re-starting my dev mongoDB instance `mongod`, and run test again through `mvn clean -Dtest=AuthServiceApplicationTests test`. I can see in the logs that `embedded-mongoDb` is downloaded from internet and tried running new `mongoDb` instance on `port=54177` with db path `dbpath=/var/folders/6m/T/embedmongo-db-2ec52647-1397-402b-9774-116d0dd7327e `. However, `undertow` started on random `port=54639` and execute the selected test class `AuthServiceApplicationTests` with success and shutdown the undertow process with `removing socket file: /tmp/mongodb-54177.sock
` in logs.

Comment: But it leftover the **testing** data in `testdb` which I can clearly see after login into mongoDb instance `127.0.0.1/27017` with data store path `/data/db`. Confused here! Why am I seeing the `testDb` in my `dev` mongoDB instance when integration test started with it's own embedded mongoDB instance at `hosts=[localhost:54177]` with data store path `/var/folders/..../embedmongo-db-2ec52647-1397-402b-9774-116d0dd7327e`. Can someone please enlighten this concern? Is it expected behaviour? or am I missing something here?