# Spring Boot Test Cannot find Properties No Matter What

Tags: java, spring-boot

I have a simple bean

```
public class MyBean {

    @Value("${propItem}")
    private boolean propItem;

    public String someMethod() {
        if (propItem) {
            return "XX";
        } else {
            return "XY";
        }
    }
}
```

I have a properties file in `src/test/resources` called `application-test.yml` which has one property

`propItem: true`

If I run my test below - I expect it to pass, but it fails because `propItem` is always `false`

```
@SpringBootTest
public class MyBeanTest {
    public void testFunc() {
       assertTrue(new MyBean().someMethod().equals("XX"); // Fails because it's "XY"
    }
}
```

Why is this a problem? I thought Spring does all these automatically, but seems not

Comment: Are you using "test" profile for test? see it for example: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38711871/load-different-application-yml-in-springboot-test. Add @ActiveProfiles("test")

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to:

- define `MyBean` as a bean by adding an stereotype annotation: `@Component`, `@Configuration` or `@Service`
- define an active profile on your test class: `@ActiveProfile("test")`

Your class should looks like this:

```
@Component
public class MyBean {

    @Value("${propItem}")
    private boolean propItem;

    public String someMethod() {
        if (propItem) {
            return "XX";
        } else {
            return "XY";
        }
    }
}
```

Your test class:

```
@SpringBootTest
@ActiveProfile("test")
public class MyBeanTest {

    @Autowired
    private MyBean myBean;

    @Test
    public void testFunc() {
       assertTrue(myBean.someMethod().equals("XX")); // Fails because it's "XY"
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You are instantiating mybean manually, this way the property will not be injected. You need to get the bean from the context.