# How do you construct a Spring Boot test that loads main and test config files?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

By default in a unit test class annotated with `@SpringBootTest`, a properties file in `/src/main/java/resources` is ignored if one exists in `/src/test/java/resources`.

How do you construct a test that loads values from both?

For example, this test will pass:

```java
@SpringBootTest(webEnvironment = SpringBootTest.WebEnvironment.DEFINED_PORT)
class PortTests {

  @Test
  void testDefaultPort(@LocalServerPort int port) {
    assertThat(port).isEqualTo(12345);
  }

}
```

If the following file exists:

`/src/main/java/resources/application.yaml`

```yaml
server:
  port: 12345
```

But that same test fails if you add the following file as well:

`/src/test/java/resources/application.yaml`:

```yaml
foo: bar
```

How do you construct a test that passes when both files exist?

Comment: Does [Load different application.yml in SpringBoot Test](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38711871/load-different-application-yml-in-springboot-test) answer your  question?

Comment: Why would you simply not copy over all needed resources to test/java/resources?  src and test resources and/or data should be decoupled as a fundamental rule.

Comment: If you want both,  add a application-test.yml in your test,  and active that profile: "test".  It will load both the application.yml in main and application-test.yml in test.

Answer (score 1):

You should have separate resources for each environment, the test has its own folder structure and should has its own different properties

**/src/main/java/resources**

**/src/test/java/resources**

Just try to copy all the properties to the test resource file and change the values based on your configuration.