# Value annotation not working in Junit test

Tags: java, spring, junit

```
@SpringBootTest
public class RuleControllerTest {

@Value("${myUrl}")
private String myUrl;
private HttpClient httpClient = HttpClients.createDefault();

@Test
public void loadAllRules() throws IOException, URISyntaxException {
    String target = myUrl + "/v2/rules";
    String json = generateHTTPget(target);

    ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();
    objectMapper.configure(DeserializationFeature.FAIL_ON_UNKNOWN_PROPERTIES, false);
    Rule[] rules = objectMapper.readValue(json, Rule[].class);

    boolean correctResponse = rules != null ? true : false;
    int httpCode = getHTTPcode(target);
    boolean correctStatus = httpCode >= 200 && httpCode <= 300 ? true : false;

    assertTrue(correctStatus);
    assertTrue(correctResponse);
}
```

I am trying to get a String from my application.properties file and insert @Value in a field in my Junit test. I have done this before in normal class, but I have null on my field in the test. I read similar questions about this problem and so far tried to create src/test/resources package and clone the application.properties there. Also tried to add the dependency

```
<dependency>
   <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
   <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
   <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>
```

and add the annotation

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
```

I get a message No tests found with test runner Junit 5 and in Problems tab i have springboottest.jar cannot be read or is not a valid ZIP file

Also tried

```
@PropertySource("classpath:application.properties")
```

as class annotation but with same result

I did try as well to :

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
```

If i hardcode the String myUrl to "http://localhost:8090" the test works so the problem is in the @Value not working

Comment: You can give a try to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32633638/testpropertysource-and-propertysource-dont-work-for-junit)

Comment: Please add your test... Just adding some snippets isn't going to work.

Comment: @M.Deinum Indeed :)) I added how my test looks like right now

Comment: You need at least a `@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)` on the test method. The `@SpringBootTest` is pretty much useless now.

Comment: @M.Deinum It was just the latest thing I tried ... With RunWith(SpringRunner.class) I get java.net.URISyntaxException: Illegal character in path at index 1: ${myUrl}/v2/rules I am not sure why the Uri starts like this

Comment: '@RunWith' annotation has been replaced by the more powerful '@ExtendWith' annotation

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Following works for me. It picks up value from  the application.properties file.

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@ContextConfiguration(initializers = ConfigFileApplicationContextInitializer.class)
public class ValueAnnotationTest {

    @Value("${myUrl}")
    private String myUrl;

    @Test
    public void test1() throws Exception {
    assertThat(myUrl).isEqualTo("http://test.com");
    }
}
```

From [Spring Boot docs](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/2.2.2.RELEASE/reference/html/spring-boot-features.html#boot-features-configfileapplicationcontextinitializer-test-utility):

> Using `ConfigFileApplicationContextInitializer` alone does not provide
>   support for `@Value("${…​}")` injection. Its only job is to ensure that
>   `application.properties` files are loaded into Spring’s Environment. For
>   `@Value` support, you need to either additionally configure a
>   `PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer` or use `@SpringBootTest`, which
>   auto-configures one for you.

Answer (score 3):

Try to use `@TestPropertySource` on your test class.

Comment: I was trying to @TestPropertySource("application.properties"), but cant figure out how to import the annotation.. It allows me to @PropertySource, but not TestPropertySource

Comment: umm you mean you cannot import annotation?? Check if you have this package https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/test/context/TestPropertySource.html

Comment: When I hardcode the String it works but with this annotation and Value I get org.apache.http.client.ClientProtocolException      org.apache.http.ProtocolException: Target host is not specified

Answer (score 1):

Please use below to get the value of the variable in Junit

```
ReflectionTestUtils.setField(YOURCONTROLLER, "variableName", valueOfString);
```

Example in case if variable is boolean. Also variable name should be same what it is in controller.

```
ReflectionTestUtils.setField(myController, "isFlag", true);
```

Also you will need to add pom dependency

```
<dependency>
<groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
<artifactId>spring-test</artifactId>
<version>3.2.0.RELEASE</version>
<type>jar</type>
<scope>test</scope>
</dependency>
```

Comment: I tried even with a newer version of spring-test 5.0.9.RELEASE and I am trying to get the variable String from the application.properties file , not from controllers and it is the same name

Comment: You mean that variable String is only used in test case not in any controller ?

Comment: I have this String variable in application.properties and I am using it only in the tests so I can change the address if needed from application.properties file, thats why I want to try avoid hardcoding it in every test, since if someone wants to change the address he would have to do it in every place

Comment: Have you tried with `@TestPropertySource("/application-test.properties")` annotation ?

Comment: Yes I tried and I double checked it now, but with same result

Answer (score 1):

You need to add

```
@PropertySource("classpath:test.properties")
```

for example:

```
@Configuration
@ComponentScan(basePackages = { "com.app.*" })
@PropertySource("classpath:test.properties")
public class MyAppConfig {
///
}
```

If you need different configurations for test or to override values in application.properties

```
@TestPropertySource(locations="classpath:test.properties")
```

for example :

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@SpringApplicationConfiguration(classes = MyApplication.class)
@TestPropertySource(locations="classpath:test.properties")
public class MyApplicationTests {

}
```