# Testing Service Layer in a multi-module Spring Application

Tags: java, spring, maven, junit

I have a project which is consisting of several modules. (web,jms,service,persistence) When I wrote tests of persistence module it worked fine as I used the below code snippet.

```
    @RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@ContextConfiguration(loader = AnnotationConfigContextLoader.class, classes = PersistenceConfig.class)
public class SomeTestClass{

    @Autowired
    SomeRepository someRepository;
```

here you can see I am using PersistenceConfig config class and it works really fine.
When It comes to test the service layer which has dependencies in JMS module where I am configuring jms properties via properties file. The problem is @PropertyResource is not being injected to test class ,I need to read that file to configure JMSConfig class.

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@ContextConfiguration(loader = AnnotationConfigContextLoader.class, classes = {PersistenceConfig.class, JmsConfig.class, CachingConfig.class})
@TestPropertySource("classpath:asynch_test.properties")
public class SomeServiceTest {

    @Autowired
    @Qualifier("somePersistenceService")
    SomeService someService;
```

Any Comment is appreciated.

Comment: this might help you: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32633638/testpropertysource-and-propertysource-dont-work-for-junit.. 
have a check on spring version

Comment: just to make sure asynch_test.properties is present in the classpath ?