# What configuration enables the evaluation of @Value annotations?

Tags: spring

I'm tying to do a very minimal programmatic/annotation based configuration of Spring, to do some command line stuff and I want to be able to inject value of some bean values from System properties.

I'm using the @Value like this:

```
@Value("${MigrateDb.task:default}")
private String task;
```

It's sort of working, but it's not evaluating the value definition, I'm just getting "${MigrateDb.task:default}" in the actual field, instead of Spring evaluating it and giving me the value of the Migrate.db.task system property (or default).

What do I need to add to my Configuration class to enable this behaviour?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try using it this way:

```
@Value("${MigrateDb.task:default}")
private String task;
```

**XML Config:**

```
<context:property-placeholder
        location="your.filelocation.properties" />`
```

**Java Config :**

```
@Bean
public static PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer propertyPlaceholderConfigurer() {

    PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer propertyPlaceholderConfigurer = new PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer();
    propertyPlaceholderConfigurer.setLocation(new ClassPathResource("file.properties"));

    return propertyPlaceholderConfigurer;
}
```

Comment: Why use SpEL for this, you don't need it and your `PropertyPlaceholderConfiguer` should be `static` and preferably be a `PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer`.

Answer (score 0):

From ShadowRay's answer, the minimum code to enable the requested behaviour is:

```
  @Bean
  public static PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer propertyPlaceholderConfigurer(){
      return new PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer();
  }
```

Method should be static as per: https://stackoverflow.com/a/14943106/924597