# Invoking Spring custom scope method

Tags: java, spring, scope

I have defined a custom scope for my Spring application. Since it is not annotated as a bean I am not able to get its instance. So my question is **how can I invoke one of the methods in my custom scope?**

Comment: you still need to define your scope as bean

Comment: @Palcente you mean I have to annotate it to get its instance? And then invoke its method like any other bean?

Comment: Yes, you should be able to make the thing that implements `Scope` a [fairly regular](http://stackoverflow.com/a/14943106/995891) bean which you can inject in both the place that registers the scope and in other places that need to interact with it.

Comment: check this out, this is ELI5 tutorial http://www.programmingforliving.com/2012/10/how-to-write-custom-bean-scope-in-spring.html